Error trying to import pgeocode ,ImportError: cannot import name 'string_types'
I have this problem importing pgeocode, ImportError: cannot import name 'string_types'
(https://i.sstatic.net/pct7D8fg.png)(https://i.sstatic.net/DaMADCh4.png)](https://i.sstatic.net/7AcjwGye.png) Thank you
I have tried importing pandas, numpy, I have updating everything and nothing seems to work,  I even reinstalled Python 3.12. My OS is Windows.I also Try downgrading numpy.
Thank you

Please edit the question to limit it to a specific problem with enough detail to identify an adequate answer.
